# How to use simultaneous of parallel and serial version of MKL?

Tags: c++, c, dll, intel-mkl

The serial and parallel version of the MKL are implemented in two different libraries. The functions of the libraries have the same name. So you can not directly load both libraries and call each of the function respectively, without having conflict in compile time.

I would like to develop a wrapper of the functions (such as OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library (GLEW)), which will have a corresponding extension for each same function and the extended function will load the parallel or sequential function from the appropriate library.
Is this a good idea? Can you suggest something else?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you always use the parallel version of MKL, and control #thread used by MKL functions.

MKL provides [void mkl_set_num_threads( int nt )](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-9999ED2B-CFD6-4687-B690-DA81E0870D67.htm) to change #thread MKL functions can use at any time.

When you set it to one, it is equal to the serial version.

Comment: This applies now, but I'm not very satisfied. I have a process, which has been parallelized  at high level. At low level (in thread of proccess) I call functions of the MKL-library (in serial mode). I have made the same examples with two different implementations, one is the parallel MKL on a single CPU and the other is serial MKL. The comparison of the two implementations has differences in time, The serial implementation is faster. This is a normal, because the parallel MKL has an overhead due to the control functions of the thread-libraries...